# apache2 tomcat7 with mod_jk dont work after system reboot

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, mod-jk, ajp

I have configured tomcat to run on port 80 with apache2 and mod_jk and this work well. If i reboot the system then the site will be the standart site from apache2. If i restart apache2 (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart) the site will come from tomcat. But why first after restart of apache2?

Anyone an idea?

Log after reboot the system (in /var/log/apache2/):

```
> mod_jk.log <
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40.296 2014] [2256:3075069696] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40.296 2014] [2256:3075069696] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40.296 2014] [2256:3075069696] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map post processing.
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40.298 2014] [2257:3075069696] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40.298 2014] [2257:3075069696] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40.298 2014] [2257:3075069696] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map post processing.

> error.log <
[Mon Sep 22 16:24:40 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.37 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 22 16:26:50 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Log after restart apache (in /var/log/apache2/):

```
> mod_jk.log <
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10.042 2014] [3599:3074443008] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10.042 2014] [3599:3074443008] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10.042 2014] [3599:3074443008] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map post processing.
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10.052 2014] [3600:3074443008] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10.052 2014] [3600:3074443008] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10.052 2014] [3600:3074443008] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map post processing.

> error.log <
[Mon Sep 22 16:29:10 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.37 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, i have tested this several times and find out that the apache2 / tomcat7 / mod_jk behavior is more crazy xD
I will show you my configurations:

```
> local: hosts <
192.168.84.129 migor
192.168.84.129 test.migor

> in tomcat server.xml <
<Host name="test.migor" appBase="myapps/test" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />

> worker.properties <
workers.tomcat_home=/var/lib/tomcat7
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7
ps=/
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1

> sitea-available/test.migor <
<Virtualhost test.migor>
    JkMount /* ajp13_worker
    ServerName test.migor
    DocumentRoot /var/lib/tomcat7/myapps/test
    ErrorLog /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/access.log common
    <Directory /var/lib/tomcat7/myapps/test>
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Now the behavior:

- After reboot under url: "test.migor/", "migor/" and my server ip 192.168.84.129 i will get the site from apache2
- After restarting apache2 i will get on migor/ and 192.168.84.129 the tomcat page from webapps and on test.migor/ the page from myapps/test. Here the problem, i expected on 192.168.84.129 the page from apache2.

Any an idea?

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, i have forget to add "NameVirtualHost test.migor" to "sitea-available/test.migor" and my config have completly overwrite default settiong of apache. Now is the behavior ok for me. With url "migor/" i can call default apache site and with url "test.migor/" i can call the tomcat homepage which is in tomcat7/myapps/test.

But this behavior will be activated only after restart of apache2 (if i have rebooted my system before). I will show for the solution and post it here. Maybe in "EDIT 3" xD

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that `jk-manager` and `jk-status` is not accurately defined in workers.property file.

Please check your workers.properties file and make following changes:

```
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status

worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
```

Cheers!!